# jquery timepicker set time click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timepicker

Jquery timepicker set button click function not working.

I tried to add a class to  `<div id="ptTimeSelectSetButton">`

using `$('#ptTimeSelectSetButton a').addClass('timePickClass');`

`<div id="ptTimeSelectSetButton">` it's a div inside timepicker

I tried to add click functions on using div id and '' tag inside the div.

unfortunately the click function not working. if anybody know the reason please share here.

[HERE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthar/0u7ambps/2/)

html page

```
Start Time <input id="sample1" type="text"></input>
End Time <input id="sample2" type="text"></input>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#sample1").ptTimeSelect();
    $("#sample2").ptTimeSelect();
    $('#ptTimeSelectSetButton a').addClass('timePickClass');
}); 
// click on div
$('#ptTimeSelectSetButton').click(function(e) {
          alert('Working with div id');
});
//or click on <a href> tag 
$(".timePickClass").click(function(e) {
    alert('working with a tag class');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div is create dynamically when the popup is shown so you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#ptTimeSelectSetButton a', function (e) {
    alert('Working with div id');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oes67kaa/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the click events inside the `$(document).ready` or use event delegation as others said:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#sample1").ptTimeSelect();
    $("#sample2").ptTimeSelect();
    $('#ptTimeSelectSetButton a').addClass('timePickClass');

    //or click on <a href> tag 
    $(".timePickClass").click(function(e) {
        alert('working with a tag class');
    });
    // click on div
    $('#ptTimeSelectSetButton').on('click', function(e) {
              alert('Working with div id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **event delegation** for dynamically created DOM elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#sample1").ptTimeSelect();
    $("#sample2").ptTimeSelect();
    $('#ptTimeSelectSetButton a').addClass('timePickClass');
}); 
// click on div
$(document).on('click', '#ptTimeSelectSetButton', function(e) {
          alert('Working with div id');
});
//or click on <a href> tag 
$(document).on('click', ".timePickClass" ,function(e) {
    alert('working with a tag class');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0u7ambps/3/)